# Connecting to WiFi where username/password is linked to Windows

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

I'm using a laptop provided by an institution, where Ubuntu and Windows is set to dual boot. The Windows installation is joined to the institution's domain.

I can connect to my institution's WiFi hotspot by using the "Use my Windows username and password" checkbox in Windows 8. (Apparently, the credentials used seem to be username=XXXINSTITUTION{myuseraccount} and password={windows_password}).

In Ubuntu 14.04, connecting using these details from network-manager does not get Ubuntu connected to the internet. It asks for the username and password, and keeps retrying, even if I provide with above data.

How should I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact problem and fixed it with dumb luck. But here's what I did.

**Edit Connections by right clicking wifi icon in top right.**

**Select domain (wifi name) you and to join, and click edit.**

**Go to Wifi Security Tab. If your problem is the same as mine, you will have options for Security, Authentication, CA Certificate, Inner Authentication, the the username and password.**

**Mess with Authentication and Inner Authentication settings.**

I was having this same problem with 14.04 and joining a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain. **I have the Authentication set to Tunneled TLS and the Inner Authentication set to MSCHAPv2. Below that it asks for my username and password.**

Sorry I'm answering this thread so long after it was posted. But it's now here forever for you OP and anyone with this kind of problem to see and use. Also sorry if this didn't solve your problem.